# thrust::min_element in-place

Tags: cuda, thrust

I look on the profiling results and see that `thrust::min_element()` calls `cudaMalloc()`, hence uses the additional memory. I do not need the array data after the reduction, so would prefer to find the minimal element in-place. Is it possible?

Comment: Your array is already in device memory?

Comment: Yes, it is already there

Comment: `thrust::min_element` is not really a reduction, but a search. This is a good question. It could be generalized to ask if it's possible to make faster search algorithms on the GPU if the algorithms are allowed to destroy the input data.

Comment: I'm sure it is. But I don't want to code it by myself. It would be great if thrust had it :)

Comment: @AdelNick the memory requirements are pretty trivial for reduction log (n) scratch space fo n elements. While there may be some ways to do parallel reduction in place, I don't think they will be the most effecient (and I don't think thrust has anything like that).

Comment: @RogerDahl min / max _is_ a reduction. You don't do search in parallel.

Comment: @Pavan: Would it be more correct to say that it's a search implemented as a reduction?

Comment: @RogerDahl: min and max are not searches. They are associative binary functions, and reduction is the general parallel application of any suitable associative binary function over an input set.

Answer (score 1):

Thrust's reductions only use `O(1)` temporary storage (actually `O(#processors))`, but if you insist on managing the allocations yourself, you can [implement your own custom allocation scheme](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/1.6.0/examples/cuda/custom_temporary_allocation.cu).